# Is there $C$ such that $ \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{b^2 + x^2} dx \leq \frac{C}{a+b} $ for all $a,b>0$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

I would like to prove that for $a,b > 0$,
$$
\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{b^2 + x^2} dx \leq \frac{C}{a+b}.
$$
where $C$ is some constant independent of $a$ and $b$.
One approach I tried was to explicitly find the anti-derivative (a function involving arctan), but it seems like there should be a simple way without having to deal with trig functions. The integrand is less than $1/(b^2 + a^2)$ for the domain of the integral, but this does not seem sufficient.  I would appreciate some intuition or some simple argument.  This particular integral appears in the solution of a PDE that I would like to understand more qualitatively.

Comment: First, you can substitute $x=b t$ to essentially make it a one variable problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the bound (originally with $C=1$) is not quite correct, but you can achieve something similar by splitting the integral and estimating each in a straightforward way:

$$I = \left(\int_a^R + \int_R^\infty\right)\frac{1}{x^2+b^2}dx \leq \frac{R-a}{a^2+b^2} + \frac1R$$

Then optimize $R$ so that $\frac{R}{a^2+b^2} = \frac1R$, i.e. $R=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, to obtain

$$I \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}-\frac{a}{a^2+b^2} \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

This should provide a decent replacement; you get $O(1/a)$ and $O(1/b)$ decay as each goes to infinity.

(Also, note that you can similar asymptotics by using the explicit formula $I = \frac1b\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\frac{a}{b})\right) $ and Taylor expanding $\arctan x$, which isn't too much more work)

EDIT: The question now asks if one can obtain $I\leq \frac{C}{a+b}$. Of course, $$(a+b)^2 = a^2+b^2 + 2ab \leq 2(a^2+b^2)$$ by Young's inequality, so we get $$I \leq \frac{2\sqrt2}{a+b}$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

- set $\displaystyle f(a)=\int_a^\infty \frac 1{b^2+x^2}dx\ $ and $\,g(a)=\dfrac 1{a+b}$
- study the function $h(a)=f(a)-g(a)$ what is the sign of $h'(a)$ ?
- what is the value of $h(0)$ ?
- can we conclude for all $a$ or is there a threshold ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's even true? For $a=b=1$ integral is $\pi/4$, which is definitely $\ge1/2$.

Comment: Ah you're right.  I missed some universal constant.

Answer (score 1):

I found a slightly different inequality. Assuming $b < a$, then for $x \geq a$,
$$(x-b)^2 \leq b^2 + x^2 \leq (x+b)^2 \\
\frac{1}{(x-b)^2} \geq \frac{1}{b^2 + x^2} \geq \frac{1}{(x+b)^2} \\
\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{(x-b)^2} \geq \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{b^2 + x^2} \geq \int_a^\infty\frac{1}{(x+b)^2} \\
\frac{1}{a-b} \geq \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{b^2 + x^2} \geq \frac{1}{a+b}$$